# I'm having trouble installing grapejuice

Tags: command-line

I'm working on a Chromebook running Linux, and after copying the zip file, I put in 'sudo apt install -y grape juice', but it doesn't find the package. I have tried copying and pasting the contents into a folder, but it has not worked

Comment: What is "grapejuice"? There is no such package in [the official repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=grapejuice)?

Comment: You are having trouble because you did not follow [the instructions](https://brinkervii.gitlab.io/grapejuice/docs/Installing-from-package.html) from upstream Grapejuice.

Comment: Packages are built for specific OS & releases, and we don't know yours thus we can't provide specific details as to what you can install using `apt` & package tools.  My samsung galaxy phone (Android) also runs Linux, as it's a kernel & rather unspecific (*you've find modern cars use Automotive Grade Linux too*) so be specific with OS/release details for helpful advice.

Comment: Are you using ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Grapejuice is a launcher for the popular Roblox platform. To install Grapejuice in Ubuntu run the following commands.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
curl https://gitlab.com/brinkervii/grapejuice/-/raw/master/ci_scripts/signing_keys/public_key.gpg | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/grapejuice-archive-keyring.gpg
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/grapejuice.list <<< 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/grapejuice-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brinkervii.gitlab.io/grapejuice/repositories/debian/ universal main'
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install -y grapejuice
```

Note that grapejuice is one word that is not separated by a space character in the `sudo apt install -y grapejuice` command.

You will need to install Wine before you can use Grapejuice. See [Ubuntu WineHQ Repository Wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) for instructions on installing Wine.